# Node.js Installation

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure if Node.js was correctly installed on my laptop. Using the instructions from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial, I ran node -- version on my command prompt, and the results are shown below. The version is shown but I'm not sure what the error message above it is saying.

[image]

Comment: Try `node --version`, without space between `--` and `version`.

Comment: It's working as expected now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a ' ' (space char) between `--` and `version`. Rather use the command:

`node -v` or `node --version`.

Or, just `node` (this will open a node console)